# Average of a column - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am new to rails and I am trying to perform some statistical analysis in a rails application. For this  need to find the mean value of the column strokes(data type int).

I have googled the problem but have trouble finding how to start. Can anyone help on where to place this line.
Scores.average(:strokes)
My table is called scores, the column is called strokes(type int). I am hoping to put the result in my views eventually.

Comment: What specifically is it you don't understand?  `@avg = Score.average(:strokes)` will give you the statistical mean/average. You can do the query in you controller and then output the variable in your view.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

Comment: Can I put this in def index to show on the index view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you want to create the average of all columns in your table you could use this in you score table

```
 #app/model/score.rb
 def self.average
      Score.average(:strokes)
 end
```

and call it in your Controller like this:

```
 #app/controller/scores_controller.rb

 Class ScoresController < ApplicationController
  def index (?)
   Score.average
  end
 end
```

Comment: Um why? `Score.average(:strokes)` will give the the mean (mean is the same as average) by `SELECT AVG("scores"."strokes") FROM "scores"` which is far more performant.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

Comment: Yes thats true. Changed  it

Comment: Its nice that you try to help however that `self.average` class method does not work since it is a circular reference and also completely unnecessary - `ActiveRecord::Base` already has an average method from `ActiveRecord::Calculations`.

Comment: Ok. I did not know that method existed. Sorry. The model function makes no sense ;) With the console i also get the  difference between the calls `Score.average("strokes")` and `Score.all.sum("ABS(strokes)")`